# What is a JWT Principal?

Tags: jwt

RFC 7519 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7519)
mentions a principal but doesn't define it.

What is a JWT Principal?

Answer (score 4):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_(computer_security)):

> A **principal** in computer security is an entity that can be authenticated by a computer system or network.

Let's consider an example where we're using JWT for user's authentication, then e.g. in the Subject Claim's definition from the RFC 7519:

> The "sub" (subject) claim identifies the principal that is the subject of the JWT.  The claims in a JWT are normally statements about the subject.  The subject value MUST either be scoped to be locally unique in the context of the issuer or be globally unique. The processing of this claim is generally application specific. The "sub" value is a case-sensitive string containing a StringOrURI value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

, principal is a specific user for whom a specific token was issued, and "sub" claim is some id of this user.